# stripe-python, should it be async?

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I need to integrate Stripe into a Django project and I noticed that there's a `stripe-python` package. This runs entirely synchronously though. Is it a bad idea to make these types of call from the main web server? Since it makes external calls, this presumably means the webserver will be blocked while we wait for a response, which seems bad.

So, should I be running this from something like Celery? Or is it fine to run on the main thread?  Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: This is good context. Thank you. If you want to post as an answer I will accept.

Comment: Thank you. I just added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a previous project, I think using it synchronously is much better from a design prospective. WIth most payments, you want to keep the user on the page until the payment goes through so they know for certain that there was no issue with the payment and you can handle any issues with the payment right there rather than taking the task from the queue and handling it. If you think about most payments you have done online, these all are happening in the main thread for this reason

Comment: It is definitely not true to say it is better to do it synchronously.. it would be better to do this async but with quality code.